# Repaired a treadmill: safety check

Tags: motor, safety

A while ago I rented a treadmill out, and it was a high end one, with a 3HP motor. It is 240V 10A (I am in AU)

Anyway long story short, we got to keep the treadmill at the end of the rental period. The company did not want to come and pick it up from us (we tried for months to get them to pick it up but they did not come) and I offered to throw it away for them (to which we kept it instead). I think the reason the cfompany did not want ti pick it back up is simply because the treadmill was used (it was rental) and we did complain of some issues with it. It overheated sometimes and shut down, and the HR monitor was not working -- for all intents and purpose, they really couldn't -- and should not have -- rented it out to anyone.

I left it outside for a few months, where it rained and whatnot. When I put it back inside to test it out, this is what happened:

1. The buttons were not all working, only some of them were working. The start button in particular did not work, so it would not start

I opened up the motor and cleaned around the PCB for a bit, there were some leaves and spider webs. Dust was plentyful and that was taken care of. Fans were also cleaned (as I assumed that that was what had caused the OH issues before). No visual damage was observed on the capacitors.

I tighten the belt, lube it up abit and lo and behold - it now turns on! Fantastic.

My concern is that, is there anything else I should be aware of? Given that it was left outside, and I only did a rudimentary maintenance of the treadmill, I do not want to motor to fail or for it to set on fire. I have tested the safety features which do work, and I am planning on letting it run for a day under the assumption that, if it were to fail, it would fail then and there and not sometime down the track. What do you guys think?

Comment: I think you got lucky. I think you should let it continue to dry out for a few weeks inside the house. Let things completely come up to temperature and humidity inside the home. And I think you should thoroughly go through it, pulling nearly everything apart and putting it back together again. I have a treadmill here that uses a slightly smaller motor and I have completely dismantled it before, so I know from experience that I'm not suggesting something you cannot do. Check the rollers and bearings. Check the motor and bearings. Check control panel and motor control boards. Etc. It's worth it.

Comment: What about the problem you already faced initially- "It overheated sometimes and shut down, and the HR monitor was not working"? Is it also fixed?

Comment: @jonk Thanks I agree I got lucky! I will let it dry for a few more weeks and see if I can completely pull it out and back together again to make sure it's well maintained inside. And possibly leaving it running for a few hours to see if any other issues persist

Comment: @PrasanDutt Unfortunately no, HR monitor did not work. The HR monitor is separately located under the console, presumably it is connected to a different board. It did not work when we got it though (though we just let that slide as we didn't really use it much)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Advice herein is offered with NO RESPONSIBILITY for outcomes.
2. I (longish ago) used to design parts of the console portion for exercise equipment. I should NOT be regarded as an expert therein but I have a good idea of what they do and are liable to do.

---

A 3 HP treadmill is ALWAYS potentially able to maim and kill people (even Australians)(and maybe even some NZers).

After the history you describe there is a somewhat higher chance of it trying to do so but it should be safe enough [tm] if suitable care is taken.

You say "the safety features do work".

(1) **ENSURE** that you understand how the user cord clip cutoff circuitry works and

**Ensure** that it is "**FAIL SAFE**".

(2) **ALWAYS USE IT.**

It is unlikely but possible that the unit will suddenly go to full speed instantly one day. This should ALWAYS be assumed to be possible with any such gear BUT more likely after spiders ants rain mice and Murphy have had their say.

**ENSURE** that you are happy with the worst case consequences of it going to full speed. Worst case is usually being flung backwards.
But, also, **ENSURE** that you cannot be trapped by the belt catching clothes or body parts at belt exit point (or anywhere else).

2000 Watts ~= 200 kg.m.s
At say 5 m/s that's about 40 kg of belt pull.
The chances of anyone directly resisting the pull on the belt manually in an emergency situation is about zero. Even Australians. So, be sure the safety systems both work AND remove belt pull fast enough to make worst case emergencies less worse.

Treadmills CAN be stalled by wedging the belt or applying braking force at a mat-roller interface. (I knew a not always well behaved sports equipment maker (no longer alive) who could and sometimes did (I was told 2nd hand) burn out competitor's treadmill motors at tradeshows by applying a shoe enclosed foot onto the belt above a drive roller. Not recommended [tm] but may give you some extreme emergency safety stop ideas.

As with any such device - have your health, accident and life insurances paid up and able to cover worst case outcomes.

Comment: Fantastic write up, much-appreciated mate! I'm prepared to handle it full force and use the safety features at all time. In terms of fire safety hazards, which is my main concern, assuming that the treadmill dried out completely inside, would you say that chance is near zero? The other possibility I can think of is if the temperature sensor became defective (preventing an automatic shutdown, leading to a potential fire). However, I did remove the casing and noticed the motor fan running fine!

Comment: @silenceislife On a non-liability YMMV basis :-) - I'd expect fire hazard would not be much affected. After it was well dried out, blowing out the motor as well as possible with compressed air may help and should do no harm. A light whiff of one of the various sprays aimed at improving insulation in such situations again MAY help but probably not needed and if used beware getting it in places where it may have secondary effects (belt-roller slippage, hot surface decomposition, ...). | I'd use it happily with due care. As ever YMMV. For interest - where in Oz. I'm in Ak NZ.

Comment: I agree, thanks again! Will use it. I am from Sydney, AU.